# How to programmatically determine if anonymous access is enabled for a SharePoint 2010 Web Application?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In Central Administration\Manage Web Applications, there is the ability to enable anonymous access on a web application through the authentication providers.  Is there a way to programmatically determine if this option is enabled?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

`web.Site.WebApplication.IisSettings[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUrlZone.Internet].AllowAnonymous`

I started with web, but you can start wherever you need obviously.  Also make sure you look at the appropriate zone.

Answer (score 1):

The SPWeb object expose the following boolean :

AllowAnonymousAccess

example :

```
web.AllowAnonymousAccess;
```

*MSDN : Gets a Boolean value that indicates whether anonymous access is allowed for the website*